# Как правильно обернуть эти JS-скрипты?

Tags: javascript

Плохо разбираюсь в семантике JS, помогите,пожалуйста.
Браузер ругается на лишние символы в данных скриптах.
Как следует их правильно обернуть,чтобы не было ошибок и конфликтов?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
const checks = document.querySelectorAll('input.form-check-input')

checks.forEach(c => c.addEventListener('click', onClick))

function onClick() {
  if ([...checks].filter(c => c.checked).length === 3) {
    const url = 'http://site.ru' + [...checks].map(c => c.value).join('')

   location.href = url
  }
};

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

const checkbox = document.getElementById('link5')

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    document.getElementById('tab1').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('tab1').style.display = 'none';
  }
}};
```

Comment: браузер явно указывает где и какой символ является неожиданным: `};` тут пропущена `)`, а тут `}};` вместо `)` вставили `}`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо. уже нашел.
Буду очень благодарен, если Вы расскажете как объединить эти два кода в один.

Comment: @Grundy const checkbox = document.getElementById('link5')

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
if (event.target.checked) {
document.getElementById('tab1').style.display = 'block';
} else {
document.getElementById('tab1').style.display = 'none';
}
})

const checkbox = document.getElementById('link6')

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
if (event.target.checked) {
document.getElementById('tab2').style.display = 'block';
} else {
document.getElementById('tab2').style.display = 'none';
}
})

Comment: не понял, что значит объединить в один?